# Hive partitioning with two columns

Tags: hive

This is more like a theoretical question
I have a hive table with 2 partition columns say col1 and col2
if I write a query like below will I use the benefits of partitioning

```
select count(*) from table A where col1='A' and col2 > '1' and col2 < '6'
```

I don't see much difference in execution time than just doing below

```
select count(*) from table A where col1='A'
```

Is my first query not able to leverage partitioning , is there any way to do that work ?

Comment: how much data are you trying to access. How are you comparing time?

Comment: first query has 70% of data compared to the second query , running the command in hue

Comment: I am talking about total table size. If you have only few MB's you are not going to see much difference. Also at that time How many other queries are running also matters. If you truly want to compare the time. `Create a different queue with let's say 30% of total resources. `

Answer (score 1):

```
if you have high values of data then definitely the first query will give much better performance.
Also if you want to compare them I would suggest you run at least 3 time the same query and then calculate the average of them.
You make get some different because so many other jobs will run parallel, So might not get enough resource then first attempt will tale longer time. I mean say they so many reason.
```